# Clustered y-axis values when using facet_wrap with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine multiple boxplots using `facet_wrap` with `ggplot2`.

I achieved the desired plots initially with one dataset:

[image]

When running the same code with a slightly different dataset, the values on the y-axis are all clustered together and not legible:

[image]

For both plots, I used `scales="free"`.

See code:

```
ecoli$site=factor(ecoli$site, levels = c("US1","US2","DS2","DS3","DS4","DS5","DS6",
"DS7","DS8_AB","DS9","DS10","FRN1","FRS1"))

ecoli_plot=ggplot(data=ecoli)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=period,y=value,group=period,fill=period),
varwidth=T)+labs(x=element_blank(), y="E.coli (MPN/100mL)", title="E.coli")+theme_classic()+
theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold",size=11))+geom_jitter(aes(x=period,y=value,color=factor(period)))

all_ecoli=ecoli_plot+facet_wrap(~site,scales="free")
```

The only difference between the two datasets are the "sites" I'm including in the plot. I used the first line of code to establish the desired order of the sites in plot.

Comment: In your second data set the `value` column is a character or factor vector, not a numeric vector. Try `ecoli$value <- as.numeric(as.character(ecoli$value))` then running the plot again.

Comment: @AllanCameron  Thank you! I added that small piece of code assigning 'value' as a numeric vector and achieved the desired plot.